# I am assigning an element to array but it shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var prev = [];
    var count = 0;
    var data = '';
    $('#add_ref').click(function(){
       var man_val = $.trim($('#manual_ref').val());
         if(($.inArray(man_val,prev))==-1){

          if(man_val != ''){
            count += 1;
            prev[1] = man_val;
            alert(prev[i);// Problem is here
            data = '<li id="45" class="as-selection-item"><a class="as-close">x</a> '+ man_val +'   <input id="notal_45" class="cls-notal" type="checkbox" value="45" name="notal_chk[]"></li>';
            $('#ul-rtl-ref-1').append(data);
        }
       }
  }
 );
```

Why it doesn't assigning value to array ?
if I write `prev[1] = "myvalue"` its also not working. Alert always shows undefined
**Edit** prev.push(man_val) shows push is not a function

Comment: What is `i`? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry in my code i is not here its a mistake

Comment: *"Edit prev.push(man_val) shows push is not a function"* Not with the code you've quoted it doesn't. In the code you've presented, `prev` is clearly an array, and arrays have `push`. So you're not quoting the actual code you're testing (for the second time, the first being the whole `i` thing).

Comment: Thanks bro, Ok I change my code to original. but without i variable its also not working. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: You've changed the code so that there is no `i` anymore, so that part of the answer below doesn't apply anymore. But what you've said about the code that you've presented is simply not credible in two different ways:

1. You've said that `prev[1] = man_val;` followd by `alert(prev[1]);` shows `undefined`, but that's simply not true of the code you've shown.
2. You've said that `prev.push` causes an error saying `push` is not a function, but in the code you've shown, `prev` is definitely an array, and arrays definitely have `push`.

My guess is that you have something you haven't shown which is either shadowing `prev` or assigning a non-array to it. But as you haven't shown that code, what you say about the code simply doesn't jibe with the code.

Hopefully the below is of some use in whatever your actual situation is.

---

> `count += 1;`
>
> `prev[1] = man_val;`
>
> `alert(prev[i]);// Problem is here`

You're using `i` there, whereas in the line above you're using `1`. You haven't shown any code declaring or initializing `i`, so we have no idea what value it may have, but apparently it doesn't have the value `1`.

If you really want to push to the array, the usual thing would be to use `push` or assign to `prev[prev.length]`. So you rcode could be:

```
prev.push(man_val);
alert(prev[prev.length - 1]);
```

or

```
prev[prev.length] = man_val;  // This will increment `prev.length`
alert(prev[prev.length - 1]); // ...which is why we're using -1 here
```

But if you do have an `i` (and you must somewhere, or trying to read a value from it like that would cause a `ReferenceError`) and you want to be using it, you want to be consistent with how you use it. For instance:

```
prev[i++] = man_val;
alert(prev[i - 1]);
```

I'm assuming `i` starts at `0` there.

Comment: yeah i is not initialized. it is typing mistake here. If I  write `alert(prev[1])` It also shows undefined.

Comment: @Farhad: Not with the code you're showing in the question it doesn't. See the update in the answer.

Comment: +1 cause even i am sure with your 2nd point...

Comment: if I put code `var prev = [];` in `$('#add_ref').click(function()` this function it works. Global array is not working on my code .

Comment: @Farhad: As I said, you appear to be shadowing it or assigning something else to it.

Comment: My problem is bottom of my js file.Because I reassigned `prev` variable value to 0 , But I didn't know. Now I changed variable name and its working. @T.J Crowder

Comment: @Farhad: Ah, good deal!

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see  variable `i` in your code. It should be-

```
prev[count] = man_val;
alert(prev[count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer 
I change variable prev to prv and `alert(prev[i]`) to `alert(prv[count])` 
I think javascript problem prev in global variable .
my final code is

```
var prv = []
var count = 0;
var data = '';
$('#add_ref').click(function(){

var man_val = $.trim($('#manual_ref').val());
if(($.inArray(man_val,prv))==-1){

    if(man_val != ''){
        count += 1;
        prv[count] = man_val;
        alert(prv[count]);
        data = '<li id="45" class="as-selection-item"><a class="as-close">x</a> '+ man_val +'   <input id="notal_45" class="cls-notal" type="checkbox" value="45" name="notal_chk[]"></li>';
        $('#ul-rtl-ref-1').append(data);
    }
}
}
);
```

It's working nice

Answer (score 0):

use [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> Mutates an array by appending the given elements and returning the new length of the array.

```
count += 1;
prev.push(man_val);
console.log(prev);
...
```

Comment: push also shows push is not a function.

Comment: @Farhad: Not with the code you've quoted it doesn't. In the code you've quoted, `prev` is quite clearly an array, and arrays have `push`.

Comment: push isnot a function .. how can that be....please don't tell me your javascript is disabled..hahaha.. :) :).. since its clear you have declared an array there.. and it should hav a push method